# Have problem with install latest amd ati drivers

Tags: drivers, ati, video, kubuntu

Hello i have problem with install ati 13.12 drivers on kubuntu 13.10. I receive this error in console

```
    Loading new fglrx-13.251 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.11.0-15-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.11.0-15-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.11.0-15-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.251/build/make.log for more information.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up fglrx-amdcccle (2:13.251-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up fglrx-dev (2:13.251-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-15-generic
^Cdpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script was interrupted
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
```

This is /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.251/build/make.log

```
DKMS make.log for fglrx-13.251 for kernel 3.11.0-15-generic (x86_64)
пт яну  3 21:04:01 EET 2014
AMD kernel module generator version 2.1
doing Makefile based build for kernel 2.6.x and higher
rm -rf *.c *.h *.o *.ko *.a .??* *.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/3.11.0-15-generic/build SUBDIRS=/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.251/build/2.6.x modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.251/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.251/build/2.6.x/kcl_acpi.o
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.251/build/2.6.x/kcl_acpi.c: In function ‘KCL_ACPI_ParseTable’:
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.251/build/2.6.x/kcl_acpi.c:999:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘(acpi_status (*)(u32,  void *, void *))handler’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
     ((acpi_table_handler)handler)(hdr);
     ^
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.251/build/2.6.x/kcl_acpi.c:999:5: note: expected ‘u32’ but argument is of type ‘struct acpi_table_header *’
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.251/build/2.6.x/kcl_acpi.c:999:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘(acpi_status (*)(u32,  void *, void *))handler’
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.251/build/2.6.x/kcl_acpi.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.251/build/2.6.x] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic'
make: *** [kmod_build] Error 2
build failed with return value 2
```

I reinstall PC with format root and home partitions but problem is same.
My video is Radeon HD5750

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find this solution on google this working for me
https://gist.github.com/moldcraft/8116528